# drawPoint on different android versions

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I made sometime ago an application that filled full screen with pixels of random colors. Also second option was to move point across screen (now I also draw circles around it).

The app worked fine on Android 4.0 and 4.1. Now I also have devices with 4.4 and 5.1 and full random screen does not work on both (I made a log message to make sure all drawPoint-s were made for all screen - they are, but my view is not displayed), point surrounded by circles works fine on 5.1.1, but on 4.4 circles are drawn, point in the center is not.

Why and what for such differences, like point not drawn? How to draw lot of points on Andoid 4.4 and 5 - to make onDraw run in background thread? My 4.0 (Micromax A90) and 4.1 are not top of CPU-GPU, 5.1 is Sony Xperia Z,if skipped frames are the issue.

Below are parts of my code:
For circles and point:

```
public class DrawView02 extends View {

Random rnd = new Random();
Paint paint = new Paint();
Paint paint2 = new Paint();
int myWidth;
int myHeight;
int myColor;
View myView;
int myCount = 0;

public DrawView02(Context context, View view) {
    super(context);
    myView = view;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    myWidth = myView.getWidth();
    myHeight = myView.getHeight();

    myColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    paint.setColor(myColor);
    paint2.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
    if (myCount==0) {
        // too much effort for one starting point
        canvas.drawPoint(myWidth - 1, myHeight - 1, paint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawCircle(myCount + 1, myCount + 1, 25, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(myCount + 1, myCount + 1, 20, paint2);
        canvas.drawCircle(myCount + 1, myCount + 1, 10, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(myCount + 1, myCount + 1, 9, paint2);
        canvas.drawPoint(myCount+1, myCount+1, paint);
    }
    myCount++;
}
```

}

For full random screen:

in Main Activity

```
public void setTimer(){
    myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myRun();
                    //Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                }
            });
        }};

    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay ms, long period ms)
    myTimer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000, 10);
    Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask set");
}

public void myRun () {
    myView.removeAllViews();
    drawView = new DrawView(myContext, myView);
    myView.addView(drawView);

}

public class DrawView extends View {

Random rnd = new Random();
Paint paint = new Paint();
int myWidth;
int myHeight;
int myColor;
View myView;

public DrawView(Context context, View view) {
    super(context);
    myView = view;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    myWidth = myView.getWidth();
    myHeight = myView.getHeight();
Log.i ("TAG", "starting to draw points");
    //MainActivity.myThread();

    for (int i=1;i<myWidth;i++){
        for (int j=1;j<myHeight;j++){
            myColor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(myColor);
            canvas.drawPoint(i,j,paint);
        }
    }

    int test = 1;
    int test2 = test;
    Log.i ("TAG", "all points are drawn");
}
```

}

Log for 5.1.1:

```
02-03 21:45:34.303 10103-10103/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: all points are drawn
02-03 21:45:35.382 10103-10103/julius.randomscreen I/Choreographer: Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Log on 4.4:

```
02-03 22:00:28.075 17419-17419/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: all points are drawn
02-03 22:00:28.075 17419-17419/julius.randomscreen D/View: [ANR Warning]onDraw time too long, this =julius.randomscreen.DrawView{41d65380 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-838,354}time =3911 ms
02-03 22:00:44.441 17419-17419/julius.randomscreen I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Actually after several "Skipped X frames" and long time 5.1 displayed my view,   4.4 had not after several minutes and many times "skipped frames".

Update:
On 5.1 view is shown as filled with random color dots only on second run of onDraw, log from start to when I see my view as expected (P.S. on my Macromax is took about 15 seconds to fill screen with dots, on Xperia Z it's two minutes):

```
02-04 04:01:50.885 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen D/TIMER: application timer set
02-04 04:01:51.906 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: starting to draw points
02-04 04:02:35.878 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: all points are drawn
02-04 04:02:38.031 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen I/Choreographer: Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-04 04:02:38.034 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: starting to draw points
02-04 04:03:07.963 20146-20159/julius.randomscreen W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.157ms
02-04 04:04:06.577 20146-20159/julius.randomscreen W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.789ms
02-04 04:04:09.007 20146-20146/julius.randomscreen I/TAG: all points are drawn
```

Comment: Try switching between `FILL` and `STROKE` on the paint object. This might be affecting the dot drawing